# [Informix]How can I auto-update timestamp when performing an UPDATE, without TRIGGER

Tags: sql, informix

In MySQL, I can create a table with a timestamp column which value gets updated automatically when other columns change:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

What would be the best way to do something similar in Informix? Can I do this without using triggers?

Comment: You can't — you would have to use a trigger.